# NGUI UILabel text blurry (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

After trying to adjust several settings I am still getting blurry text in my NGUI labels. Does anyone know what the issue could be? I tried increasing the font size.

Below is a screenshot that demonstrates. Why is the NEW HIGH SCORE text not high resolution?

[image]

UPDATE: 
I turned on MakePixelPerfect but the text is still blurry:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either a result of font scaling from a font atlas with mip-mapping set to true or it is a result of MakePixelPerfect not being set.

Turn off mip mapping on your font atlas or make sure your labels and parent hierarchy objects run MakePixelPerfect(). Select your label and press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)+[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)+[p](/questions/tagged/p). This should enforce the pixel perfect setting for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I turned on MakePixelPerfect but the text is still blurry. I am using the Arimo20 (UIFont) that comes with NGUI, could that be the issue?

Comment: I think I solved the issue. I have now selected to use a "Unity" font instead of the ones that come with NGUI. These seem to work better.

Comment: I would have to assume that your Arimo20 is only designed to be in 20 size. That will be why it was blurring.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen grabs you are using bitmap font right?
If so,

1. Select texture used by that font
2. In Inspector select texture type as GUI

This will remove compression. Also make sure your Max Size isnt smaller than texture

[image]